# Web scraping html table in R, but the output remains empty

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data in the table at : https://www.flashscore.com/football/france/coupe-de-la-ligue-2005-2006/results/

I wrote the following code, but the output `results` remains empty.

```
library (rvest)
url <- "https://www.soccer24.com/france/coupe-de-la-ligue-2005-2006/results/"
results <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[3]/table') %>%
  html_table()
```

Does anyone know why `results` is empty and how to scrape this table ?

Comment: Try doing the steps one-by-one instead of piping everything at once, so you can figure out which call is giving you the unexpected result.

Comment: The results table you're trying to scrap the data from is loaded using an Ajax call, so the reason you're getting an empty result is that the result itself doesn't exist. Either try to dig and find which call is loading the results and call it directly, or use selenium to load the whole page.

Comment: Thanks @Ayoub_B, it works well with Rselenium !